# Module Separation

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to figure out how I can work with module separation with codeigniter.

Lets say I have a news module where its inside of the application folder and inside the news module folder I have a controllers, models, views folders and files inside of those.

Do I need something additional to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure if Codeigniter supports that out of the box. In CakePHP, that would be a [plugin](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/plugins.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to work with modules in codeigniter you can use Modular Extensions - HMVC which makes codeigniter modular. Here is the link https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/wiki/Home

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I had a friend tell me about this and I installed it and working with it now however I have $this->load->model('news/newsmodel'); which is inside a normal controller and want to load this model which is inside of the news module and its saying it can't find the model specified.